# Java Lock.lock() and Lock.lockInterruptibly()

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, interrupted-exception

I would like to know how locks are implemented in Java.
In some tutorials I found that they should be implemented using wait() and notify()/notifyAll() and some boolean flags (it might be much more complicated than that,but basically that should be like that)

```
class SimpleLock {

  private boolean locked=false;

  public synchronized void lock() throws InterruptedException {
    while (locked)
      wait();
    locked=true;
  }

  public synchronized void unlock() throws InterruptedException {
    locked=false;
    notify();
  }

}
```

but I know that interface Lock defines two methods, Lock.lock() that can't be interrupted and Lock.lockInterruptibly() that can and throws InterruptedException in order to deal with the evenience.

If locks were implemented using wait(),shouldn't them be interrupted by a call to Thread.interrupt() ?

So how are locks really implemented? I think that they're based on other Java low-level synchronization facilities (like synchronized and wait()/notify()), but I don't know how.

Comment: I voted to close since I think this cannot be answered on SO. The locking **is** complicated and anything but trivial. Boris gave a link to the source but explaining it completely would (IMHO) be to broad for SO. But as I said - only my opinion.

Comment: @Fildor I don't need a thorough explanation of Java locking inner workings. I just want the big picture

Answer (score 4):

Locks are implemented using other technique. They use `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` under the hood. It uses [LockSupport.park()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#park()) which calls Unsafe's `public native void park(boolean var1, long var2)`.

Actually threads waiting in `Lock.lock()` could still be interrupted, but this wouldn't be shown to a user, because `InterruptedException` won't be thrown. Thread will wake up after interruption, then clear interruption flag and try to acquire the same lock again.

The `Lock.lockInterruptibly()` acts another way, when interruption occurs it will throw an exception, so user can handle it the way he desires.

Comment: so, at the end, low level syncronization is a the bottom of it?

Comment: @Luca Not sure what exactly you define as "low level synchronization" but if you dig deeper and deeper you'll sooner or later probably end up in a native call. Is it that's what you wanted to know?

Comment: Yes, I slightly edited my answer - low level syncronization in this case will be an Unsafe's function `public native void park(..)`

Comment: @Fildor sorry, no, what I meant by low level synchronization was not so low level... I meant JAVA low level synchronization facilities like wait()/notify() or synchronized code.
As it turns out, it is implemented as low level system calls/native code isn't it?

Comment: _...Thread will wake up after interruption..._  That's misleading.  A thread that is interrupted while it's blocked in `Lock.lock()` won't "wake up" _becauase_ of the interruption:  It will wake up if and when it is able to acquire the lock.

Comment: Actually you are wrong, lock() is implemented using LockSupport.park(..) and in JavaDoc it is said that park() returns when: Some other thread invokes unpark with the current thread as the target; or Some other thread interrupts the current thread; or The call spuriously (that is, for no reason) returns.  So interruption will wake it up, but after that condition would be checked and another park(..) happens.